# Node.js translator

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am trying to create a back end for my front-end web page using Node.JS. The web page is using google translate API and translates the users word. At the moment I am able to get it to work when I hard code the word and the language to/from. What i am trying to do is retrieve the word they input and the language they want to translate to.

Code from front end

```js
function translateWord() {

    var url = 'http://localhost:8085';
    var endpoint = '/translate';

    var fromLang = document.getElementById("fromLang").value;
    var toLang = document.getElementById("toLang").value;
    var word = document.getElementById("wordInput").value;

    var payload = {"word": word, "from": fromLang, "to": toLang};
    console.log(payload);

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

    http.open("POST", url+endpoint, true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        var DONE = 4;       // 4 means the request is done.
        var OK = 200;       // 200 means a successful return.
        if (http.readyState == DONE && http.status == OK && http.responseText) {
            var reply = http.responseText;
            document.getElementById("mainBody").innerHTML = reply;
        }
    };


    var params = JSON.stringify(payload);

    // Send request
    http.send(params);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Translation Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    <div>
    <h1> Translation Demo </h1>

    <p>Word:<input id="wordInput" type="text"></p>

    <p>From:
    <select id="fromLang">
        <option value="en" selected>English</option>
        <option value="fr">French</option>
        <option value="es">Spanish</option>
        <option value="ru">Russian</option>
    </select>

    To:
    <select id="toLang">
        <option value="en">English</option>
        <option value="fr" selected>French</option>
        <option value="es">Spanish</option>
        <option value="ru">Russian</option>
    </select>
    </p>

    <button onclick="translateWord()">Translate</button>

    <p id="mainBody">Translation here.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the back end I am having trouble with (this part works because its hard coded).

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var cors= require('cors');
router.use(cors());
router.post('/translate', function(req, res)
{
    var payload = req.body;
    var word = "hello";
    var json = { from: 'en', to: 'fr' };

    const translate = require('google-translate-api');
    translate(word, json).then(function (resolve, reject){res.send(resolve.text.toString());});

});

module.exports = router;
```

To be able to grab the word and language, I tried doing something along the lines of this. Also I have it going to port 8085 so that's not the problem.

```
var payload = req.body;
var word = req[word];
var from = req[from];
var to = req[to];
var json = { from: 'from', to: 'to' };
```

When i try doing it this way i receive this error.

```
(node:6892) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Could someone point me in the right direction as to what I am doing wrong? I have been trying to solve this for awhile and haven't been able to.

Comment: My guess is that the JSON data can't be read. I generally use [`body-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) for this. Install it in you project: `npm i -S body-parser`, add `const bodyParser = require('body-parser');` at the top of your JS, create a JSON parser instance: `const jsonParser = bodyParser.json();` before your route, and declare your route like so: `router.post('/translate', jsonParser, function...`. You should then be able to access your JSON's properties, **but** your last snippet is wrong. It should be `var word = req.body.word; ...`. Tell me if that works for you

Comment: Thank you, ill try it out when i get back home.

Comment: Hey man I tried this out, and it worked. I just wanted to say thank you for taking the time to help me out

Comment: Glad I could help! I posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, ExpressJS won't be able to parse JSON post data. To solve this, you can use the [`body-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) module.

Install it:

```
npm i -S body-parser
```

And use it like so in your code:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // <----------------------------
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();      // <----------------------------
var router = express.Router();
var cors= require('cors');
router.use(cors());
router.post('/translate', jsonParser, function (req, res) // <-----------
{
    /* ... */
});

module.exports = router;
```

Then, inside that function, you'll be able to access your data:

```
var word = req.body.word;
var json = {
    from: req.body.from,
    to: req.body.to
};
```